How to get string/regex replace preview (like in VS Code) in Emacs, with a single hotkey?
What I want
In VS Code, I can press Ctrl + Shift + h and get a convenient preview (see screenshot) of replace candidates. It allows to navigate all matches, and do a replacement with a hotkey.

What already works
In Emacs, to get the same functionality, I can run:

Run counsel-rg (or other search)
Switch from minibuffer to ivy-occur
Convert ivy-occur to wgrep buffer

That's 3 key chords, each of them more verbose than VS Code's, if done by Emacs guidelines.

What I've tried
I would like to run steps 1-3 in Emacs, using just 1 hotkey. The closest I was able to get is this code:
(defun counsel-rg-to-wgrep ()
  (interactive)
  ;; (counsel-rg)
  (run-at-time nil nil (lambda ()
                         (ivy-wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode)))
  (ivy-occur))

But it still has to be invoked from a search mini-buffer (also, inverse order and run-at-time are necessary here, trust me). If I uncomment (counsel-rg) call, buffer with the search results doesn't open, and I get this error in Messages buffer:
ivy-occur: No completion session is active

Question
How can I make all 3 steps work with a single hotkey?

I have no idea what "I can press Ctrl + Shift + h and get a convenient preview of replace results" actually means.  What results?  All you typed was one key chord.  You don't explain the process, or what the "preview" consists of.  Assume that no one reading your question knows anything about VS Code (or counsel or ivy or ...) and instead explain in detail what you want to happen...

What does ivy-occur gain you that you didn't already have from your grep results?  I don't know why you wouldn't go directly from grep -> wgrep.

@phils, counsel-rg provides (through ivy) a convenient interactive list of matches in mini-buffer, as you type in the regex.
ivy-occur allows to convert that minibuffer into a buffer matching wgrep format.
In ideal scenario, I would like to see that interactive mini-buffer, then jump to wgrep right after I press 'Enter', with query-replace-regexp already started and supplied with the string I typed in the mini-buffer.
I'm used to having a very convenient shortcut for this in VS Code, but in Emacs I feel like I'm playing Rachmaninoff on piano, just to get basic stuff done.

Have you tried xref-find-references? Calling M-x xref-find-references followed by M-x xref-query-replace-in-results may do what you want

To automatically start query-replacing on the xref results, you could use a hook like (add-hook 'xref-after-update-hook (lambda () (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer "*xref*")) (call-interactively #'xref-query-replace-in-results)))

@Rorschach, I don't think TAGS file + xref- functions is a suitable solution for me. I'm writing a literate program, use docstrings often, and sometimes comments. Since variable name or specific term can appear across those formats, I need something that can search and replace text generally.

With a name like ivy-occur I would expect it to be using occur and occur-edit-mode rather than wgrep?  I do see 'grep' content in your screenshot, though.  Regardless, I suggest you implement a custom my-ivy-occur-edit command which calls ivy-occur and then calls the edit command, and you can bind that in the ivy keymap (either replacing the original command, or as some alternative key sequence).

I was able to get what I want with the following code. I'm new at Elisp, so refactoring suggestions welcome.
There is one thing that I couldn't get working - ivy's interactive list of matches in minibuffer, when typing in the search string.
This solution requires 3 packages: ivy, counsel, replace+.el.
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/")
(load "~/.emacs.d/elisp/replace+.el")

(defun get-initial-input-for-replace ()
      nil)
(setq-and-tell-customize 'search/replace-default-fn
                         'get-initial-input-for-replace)

(defun query-replace-regexp-with-initial-input (input)
  (eval
   '(let ((original-fn (symbol-function 'initial-input-for-replace)))
      (fset 'get-initial-input-for-replace (lambda () (regexp-quote input)))
      (unwind-protect
          (call-interactively 'query-replace-regexp)
        (fset 'get-initial-input-for-replace original-fn)))
   t))

(defun rapid-replace-across-git-repo ()
  "Opens up wgrep buffer with query-replace-regexp started"
  (interactive)
  (eval 
   '(let* ((thing (ivy-thing-at-point))
           (search-str (read-string "Enter at least 3 chars to replace: " thing)))
      (run-at-time
       nil nil
       (lambda ()
         (run-at-time
          nil nil
          (lambda ()
            (run-at-time
             nil nil
             (lambda ()
               (query-replace-regexp-with-initial-input search-str)
               ))
            (ivy-wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode)))
         (ivy-occur)))
      (counsel-git-grep search-str))
   t))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-h") 'rapid-replace-across-git-repo)

